# Why won't my iTunes store open?

Tags: itunes

It was working fine one day.  Then on the next, I tried to access the store and received this message:

**Your request could not be completed.**
The item you've requested is not currently available in the US store.

I haven't requested anything.  Closing iTunes and reopening doesn't help.  Suggestions?

**SOLVED:** An upgrade from version 6 to v10 solved it.  Thank you Alexandru and Kiwi.

Comment: What Operating System are you running?

Comment: @Force Flow:Vista (dun dun duh!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging out and back into the store (menu item `Store` > `Sign Out`) and see if that gets it working properly.

Also, if you ignore this message and keep using iTunes, are there any other problems?

Comment: It didn't work.  No other problems that I know of.